# why my code is not working about CameraRoll in android(as3)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, actionscript, camera, camera-roll

```
import flash.media.CameraRoll;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.media.MediaPromise;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.events.MediaEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

backbtn6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, back);

var cameraroll:CameraRoll;
var loader:Loader;
var promise:MediaPromise;
var bitmap:Bitmap;
var bitmapdata:BitmapData;

openpic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, selectpic);
function selectpic(e:MouseEvent):void
{
if(CameraRoll.supportsBrowseForImage)
{
    cameraroll = new CameraRoll();
    cameraroll.addEventListener(MediaEvent.SELECT, loadpic);
    cameraroll.browseForImage();
}

}

function loadpic(e:MediaEvent):void
{
promise = e.data as MediaPromise;
loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showpic);
loader.loadFilePromise(promise);
}

function showpic(e:Event):void
{
if(bitmap != null)
{
    removeChild(bitmap);
}

var originalWidth:int = Bitmap(e.currentTarget.content).width;
var originalHeight:int = Bitmap(e.currentTarget.content).height;

bitmapdata = new BitmapData(originalWidth,originalHeight);
bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapdata);
bitmap.bitmapData = Bitmap(e.currentTarget.content).bitmapData;

bitmap.x = 0;
bitmap.y = 0;

addChild(bitmap);
}
```

it's my as3 code for android using AIR.
I wrote down this code seeing ather people's code.
but it's not working in my android phone.
what's the metter with my code...help me..
how can I do??

If yoy have any solutions, Its my pleasure for developing.
I'm just one month studying as3

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Comment: "it's not working" is not enough as a description of a problem. Elaborate by telling what it's supposed to do and what it's actually doing.

Comment: I saw my example apk opens cameraroll. But when I select a image, It didn't displays on my screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the few details mentioned in your questions, I think this is a problem of permissions and the code is fine. Try to add this permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

You can add it directly to your `your_app-app.xml`, where *your_app* is the name of your application ( project ), before `</application>` like this :

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/15.0">

    <!-- ... -->

    <android>
        <manifestAdditions>
            <![CDATA[<manifest>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
            </manifest>]]>
        </manifestAdditions>
    </android>
</application>
```

Of course, don't touch the other content of your XML, you have just to add ( or edit if already exist ) the part `<android>...</android>`.

Or simply using **AIR xxx for Android Settings** dialog, where `xxx` is the version of AIR, accessible from the **File** menu, then go to **Permissions** tab and select the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission like this ( of course this is for Flash ) :

[image]

If you still always got nothing, try to add an `ErrorEvent` event listener to your `CameraRoll` object to catch errors :

```
cameraroll.addEventListener(
    ErrorEvent.ERROR, 
    function(e:ErrorEvent):void { 
        log.text = e.text;
    }
)
```

Hope that can help.